# moderator voting to close

Tags: feature-request

In a comment to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17190/why-are-more-powerful-tools-using-higher-voltage) Kortuk says

> I cannot cast a single close vote, ever. This has been requested but it has been decided that moderators only cast complete votes.

Was it discussed here on meta? If so, I can't find it, but I would like to know the reasons. I think a mod should have the right to a personal opinion too, and say: "Look, *personally* I would think this should be closed, but I want to see what others think", instead of: "Look, I would think this should be closed, so it *will* be closed." Big difference, if you ask me.
OTOH, the mod would still be able to cast a vote by creating a second non-mod account, but I think this won't work at all.

Comment: I'm not a moderator, but this sounds like a good idea to me.  In many cases there is some gray area and if I were a moderator I'd like to be able to add a single vote to the mix instead of unilateraly deciding.  Of course moderators must still have the right to close without additional votes when they feel that is appropriate.

Comment: @Olin - Yes, the two must remain possible. That's maybe not so clear in my question.

Answer (score 4):

This was discussed on the network-wide meta a while ago:

[Add a way for moderators to cast a normal, non binding close/open vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41062/add-a-way-for-moderators-to-cast-a-normal-non-binding-vote)

Moderators can just comment on a question that they think it should be closed, those comments usually carry quite some weight and often convince high-reputation users to cast their votes.

Answer (score 1):

This has already been discussed, but a major reason it is an issue now and was not much of an issue before we graduated is number of high rep users.

Right now the three moderators take away three users that know the ropes and would be actively voting to close when needed. As our site progresses and we get more users whom can vote to close you will find that this need goes away and we will only really react to flags when there is a clear need.

Comment: We will always react to flags, but we will have to act unilaterally less often when there are more users.

Comment: @KevinVermeer, and when our numbers build up like they did pre-graduation you will see how often the bad questions are closed and bad answers deleted before you can even get there.